# Finding a dense collection in $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C$ denote the set of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Define $$d(f,g)=max\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}$$ Is there a countable collection in $C$ that is dense under this metric? (no need to prove that the collection is dense)

I don't know how to prove that a set is dense when I can't use $U\cap S\neq \emptyset$ for any open set $U$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Consider the collection of piecewise linear functions with rational vertices ( except for the $x$-s of the ends perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the simplest answer, but the Weierstraß approximation theorem states that the polynomials are dense. In fact one can restrict to polynomials with rational coefficients, which forms a countable set.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)